# How to display images from a cell in Google Sheets in a merged Google Docs document using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

How to insert image from cell in googlesheet, into merged document in googledocs?

I have a template googledocs which connected to a googlesheets.  In the googlesheet I have table like picture 1, and the items is merged in the googledocs template (picture 2).  Everything is fine except the image of signature.  I use an appscript for merging the docs. In the merge document only shows "Imagecell" replace for "Tandatangan" instead of image of "Tandatangan".  So, can we make the signature show (as it showed in googlesheet) in the merged googledocs? Thank you in advanced.

[image: Picture 1, table from googlesheet]
[image: Picture 2. template googledocs]

Here is the appscript

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('CLT'); //Ini membuat menu CLT
  menu.addItem('Cetak CLT', 'buatfiledoc'); //Ini membuat sub menu Cetak CLT dengan fungsi buatfiledoc
  menu.addToUi();} //Ini supaya menunya bisa diklik
  
function buatfiledoc() {
  //Ini ID TEMPLATE file doc dari googledoc.
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('idididididididididididid');
  
  //Ini ID folder tempat menyimpan file googledocs yang akan dibuat. 
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderfolderfolder');
  
  //Ini tempat mengambil data yang akan dimerge dari googlesheet yang ada di tab (Rekap CLT) ke dalam googledocs
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Rekap CLT');
  
  //Ini mengambil seluruh data di dalam tab Rekap CLT.
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  //Ini mengecek setiap row
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    //Cek kalau row nol (menurut Javascript, row 0 adalah baris kesatu, dalam kasus ini adalah header dari tabel) maka akan dilanjut.
    if (index === 0) return;

    //Cek kalau kolom ke-8 (ingat yah javascrip kolom mulai dari nol), sudah ada isinya (dokumen sudah dicetak) maka akan berlanjut ke baris berikutnya.
    if (row[8]) return; 

    //(Cek kalau belum diberikan nomor surat, tidak akan dibisa dicetak, jadi kasih nomor surat dulu, barulah bisa dicetak)
    if (row[1]=="") return; 
    
    //ini membuat nama file supaya kalau mau cari file di dalam googledrive nya gampang, nama dibuat berdasarkan nama yang CLT ditambah dengan tanggal awal CLT.
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[3]}, ${row[4]} CLT` , destinationFolder); 

    //Kalau sudah ada namanya, maka file tersebut diambil ID filenya. 
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())

    //Sesudah dibuat copy dan diambil ID filenya, maka diambillah isi suratnya. 
    const body = doc.getBody();
    

    //Ini daftar tujuan email
    var daftaremail= ["xxxx@gmail.com", "zzzz@gmail.com", "yyyy@gmail.com", "rrrr@gmail.com"];
    var nama = row[3];
    
    //Ini kita mengganti semua yang di dalam tanda {{}} dengan yang ada dari googlesheet. 
    body.replaceText('{{Tanggal}}', new Date(row[2]).toLocaleDateString('id-ID', { day: 'numeric' , month: 'long',year: 'numeric' }));
    body.replaceText('{{Nama}}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{{Awal}}', new Date(row[4]).toLocaleDateString('id-ID', { day: 'numeric' , month: 'long',year: 'numeric' }));
    body.replaceText('{{Akhir}}', new Date(row[5]).toLocaleDateString('id-ID', { day: 'numeric' , month: 'long',year: 'numeric' }));
    body.replaceText('{{Alasan}}', row[6]);
    body.replaceText('{{Nomorsurat}}', row[9]);
    body.replaceText('{{NPK}}', row[10]);
    body.replaceText('{{Jabatan}}', row[11]);
    body.replaceText('{{Kaipi}}', row[12]);
    body.replaceText('{{Kabid}}', row[13]);
    body.replaceText('{{Dirmed}}', row[14]);
    body.replaceText('{{Dirsdm}}', row[15]);
    body.replaceText('{{Tandatangan}}', row[7]);  //--> still error, can not show image.
    
    //Setelah selesai diganti, maka dokumen dishare viewersnya, sesuai dengan daftar email yang ada. perhatikan cara penulisan daftar email.
    doc.addViewers(daftaremail);

    //Setelah selesai dishare, maka dokumen disave dan diclose.
    doc.saveAndClose();

    //Simpan file nya di dalam url. 
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    
    //Tulis file tersebut ke dalam kolom 9 di dalam googlesheet.
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 9).setValue(url);
    
    
    //Ini fungsi untuk mengirim emailnya, perhatikan daftar tujuan email, berbeda dengan penulisan di appscript.
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "yyyy@gmail.com, zzzz@gmail.com, rrrr@gmail.com, xxxx@gmail.com",
      subject:"Permohonan CLT "+nama,
      body: "Yth SDM, \n\n berikut kami lampirkan permohonan CLT "+nama+". \n\n Atas perhatiannya kami ucapkan banyak terima kasih. \n\n Hormat kami, \n\n Ramzi. \n\n"+url
      })
    
    //Munculkan toast, kalau semuanya sudah dicetak dan dikirim via email. :)
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("CLT sudah dicetak, dan sudah dikirim ke email."); 
  })
  
}
```

I have no idea to try.